# Are we using American or British English for tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags

As a Brit my natural tendency is obviously to go with British English but I was just editing the [Webform tag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webform) excerpt and I was torn between using "personalised", or "personalized". The latter is already included in the main tag wiki so I didn't know whether to change both to British, change both to American, or leave the one that's already there alone and updated just the excerpt to use British English.

I know it's of very little importance but are there any official Stack Exchange guidelines on this?

Comment: Doesn't this question also apply to questions, answers, comments, chats and what not? Consider editing your question accordingly if you think it does. and by the way, "as somebody born in the land where Drupal was born", I'm not sure which one to use, but I'd like to see some official statement about it. My best bet is like this: the SE family of site is USA "inspired" (sometimes I get chocked by some of its rules, but you accept them, try to avoid them or otherwise you better quit), so it seems to me that its language should match that also, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any official reference on Meta Stack Overflow, but in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48966/140449) to [What's the deal with retagging from UK English to US English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/whats-the-deal-with-retagging-from-uk-english-to-us-english), Marc Gravell says:

> A related issue is "correcting" the language in the title/body. In the case of the question in hand, the UK term seems entirely correct. In general, I have to concede (and I'm UK) that the US mis-spellings have become the standard. Much like the accidental referer/referrer. We're stuck with color etc, and too many "z"s to be helpful, but such is life ;-p

There are other differences between American and British English, such as the usage of punctuation in quotes.

I would say that it is preferable being constant in the used spelling, and as for the what noted from Marc Gravell, I would choose the American English spelling.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Apparently the standard is to use US-English for tags. For questions/answers there is no standard as such. This is endorsed by Jeff Atwood so I think is the definitive answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us